# iphone sdk stay the selection colour of cell in UItableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to get the selection cell still in the selected state in uitableview. Actually I am pushing a view from a tableview when came back then the selection cell is deseleted. I want to be show the previous selection cell when came back also how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In `didselectrowatindexpath` use the method  `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` and the row stays selected.

Answer (score 0):

when you are going and coming back from anotherview make sure that save the selectedCell and then in viewwillappear method reloaddata.In cellforindexpath write the code of selection style uitableviewcellselectionstyleblue.

Answer (score 0):

first, you can store the selected indexPath in user default in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.(maybe you can store a indexPath that is bigger than your table view's row count to indicate initialization stage, which means that no row has ever been selected)
then, you can load the stored indexPath in the viewDidLoad method using

```
tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> scrollPosition:<#(UITableViewScrollPosition)#>
```

meanwhile, you can do some check (like mentioned above or something else) to check if there's nothing selected yet.(saving a bool in user defaults works, too)